# Has anyone tried how to use vision api(VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest) in ios 11?

Tags: ios, coreml, apple-vision

I am studying currency recognition problems which is related to the Vision SDK of iOS11. 
I'm having trouble handling `VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest`, which determines the perspective warp matrix needed to align the content of two images. But I couldn't find how to send two images parameters into this API, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Vision framework flow is always the same: Request -> Handler -> Observation

Example:

```
// referenceAsset & asset2 can be:
//     CGImage - CIImage - URL - Data - CVPixelBuffer
// Check initializers for more info
let request = VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: asset2, options: [:])

let handler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
try! handler.perform([request], on: referenceAsset)
if let results = request.results as? [VNImageHomographicAlignmentObservation] {
    print("Perspective warp found: \(results.count)")
    results.forEach { observation in
        // A matrix with 3 rows and 3 columns.
        print(observation.warpTransform)
    }
}
```

Comment: YES，sure it is. I will supplement the objective-C version as followed

Answer (score 0):

```
-(matrix_float3x3)predictWithVisionFromImage:(UIImage *)imageTarget toReferenceImage:(UIImage*)imageRefer{

    UIImage *scaledImageTarget = [imageTarget scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(224, 224)];
    CVPixelBufferRef bufferTarget = [imageTarget pixelBufferFromCGImage:scaledImageTarget];
    UIImage *scaledImageRefer = [imageRefer scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(224, 224)];
    CVPixelBufferRef bufferRefer = [imageRefer pixelBufferFromCGImage:scaledImageRefer];

    VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest* request = [[VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest alloc]initWithTargetedCVPixelBuffer:bufferTarget completionHandler:nil];

    VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest* imageRequest = (VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest*)request;
    VNImageRequestHandler* handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc]initWithCVPixelBuffer:bufferRefer options:@{}];
    [handler performRequests:@[imageRequest] error:nil];
    NSArray* resultsArr = imageRequest.results;
    VNImageHomographicAlignmentObservation* firstObservation = [resultsArr firstObject];
    return firstObservation.warpTransform;
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to actually merge the images using the warpTransform matrix?